# How to access personal apache2 server from internet

Tags: apache-http-server

I'm running apache2 server on my computer and I would like to access it from internet but I can't seems to get it to work.

My apache2 port is open at 80.
I have set up port forwarding 80 to 80 on my computer to static ip of my server running apache2.
I tried to open up my apache2 server by typing internet IP in the browser and it's port number.

But I can access my apache2 server from lan but not from internet.

Can someone tell me if I'm missing something?

Comment: What IP address are you using to access it from the internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://thetechnofreak.com/technofreak/localhost-online-apache/

I think if you follow all these steps, you should be all right.

Or perhaps software like LogMeIn Hamachi is more like what you're looking for? http://alternativeto.net/software/hamachi/?sort=rank

Comment: Thank you it was fire wall after all.  However despite me following the steps in the first link I couldn't get my packets to go pass firewall and turn off firewalls to get it working.

Comment: Also, linked port tester within first link is down and here is the link I have used.  http://www.mynetworktest.com/ports.php

Comment: Just to make sure. Your issue is solved, right? You seem to imply maybe it's not. oo'

Comment: Well, I have to take down firewall to get it working despite me putting rules for for port 80 accepting all IP address.  But since I'm planning on having a linux server soon I don't foresee this as a problem.

Comment: Well, all rightie, then.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a simple home setup, you have a computer running apache and accepting requests on port 80. It sounds like apache is running and I presume you can access it using the local loopback address, `http://127.0.0.1`. You don't need to specify port `80`, but it won't hurt.

Your server will also have an IP address on your local network, perhaps something like `192.168.1.12`. This is a private IP that only has meaning on your home network and was either provided by your router (dynamically using DHCP), or has been statically defined by you. You can test whether your server accepts requests through it's firewall by using a 2nd computer on your network and browsing you server's private IP, `http://192.168.1.12` in my example.

Your router will have both a public and private IP address. To access your web server, you will have to tell your router to forward all requests received on the public IP address to your private server IP address.

You need to use your router's public IP address to access your web server from the internet. If you don't have a static public IP, then your ISP assigns one dynamically. You will need to use a dynamic DNS service if you wish to access a dynamically assigned IP address consistently.

Comment: Also, don't forget that some routers won't let you hit the public IP of the router from within the network. Get a friend to test it out for you from outside your network.