# Change name and address of Local IP address

Tags: ip, home-networking

I'm now starting to build a simple webserver in Python and I'm wondering how the IP addresses work. On my computer I stated in my network center a specific static IP address and this address works when sending or receiving messages through the webserver. The IP address is a local one of the form 192.168.0.x How can I get a global one so I can access the webserver from outside of the home network? Can I give a name to the LOCAL IP address so I can access it through: "mywebserver" instead of "192.168.0.1"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access personal apache2 server from internet](http://superuser.com/questions/529699/how-to-access-personal-apache2-server-from-internet)

Comment: Either connect the server directly to the modem, or configure port forwarding on your router. The exact steps for the latter approach are device-specific.

Answer (score -1):

As follow steps:
1. Apply for a free domain from domain provider company.
2. Get your external IP with CMD "$ curl ipecho.net/plain ;echo", that should be      your router outside IP.
3. Bind your external IP to Applied domain.
4. Add a Map to your router, the Map maps all 80 port traffic to your internal web server "192.168.0.1".
5. It works.

Comment: Sorry, but this advice is incorrect.  Binding to a valid IP address has nothing to do with getting a free domain.  You have not addressed the key question of it being a dynamic address or how you handle dynamic DNS issues, and the bit about "Bind your external IP to Applied domain" makes little sense, and the mapping you are talking about (better called port forwarding or pinholing) implies -correctly- that the external IP address is not actually bound to the web server - but fails to mention that fact, nor the key related fact that this will only work when connected from outside the network.

Comment: Thank`s for pointing out incorrect things of my answer.