# Reaching hosts in a private (Home-) network from the internet

Tags: networking, dns, subdomain

I am a new to networking and I have a question: I have a domain for the dynamic IP of my router.

Is there a way of using subdomains to reach different hosts in my network E.g. I have an SSH server on my Raspberry Pi and I want to reach it over the internet —> ssh username@raspi.mydomain.de -p 22

I know I can do port forwarding in my router but I don’t want to have so many different port for each PC on my network.

Is this possible?

Comment: “Is this possible?” - Yes; With port forwarding

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access personal apache2 server from internet](https://superuser.com/questions/529699/how-to-access-personal-apache2-server-from-internet)

Comment: I don't know if this precise question is the perfect duplicate, but I do know this question has been asked and answered many times. It would be a good idea to start with some of those.